# Is there any side effects of activating the video and rich media features for a site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, feature-activation, communication-site

Based on my requirement, I need to activate the video and rich media features on the site collection level.

I am trying to find if there are any side effects of doing so but not able to find any.

Below is the documentation I found online.

[Use the video and rich media feature in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-video-and-rich-media-feature-in-sharepoint-4be4b56f-65b1-46e2-9e68-a6bd2d491b88)

[Upload video, audio, or pictures to an Asset Library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/upload-video-audio-or-pictures-to-an-asset-library-74b1fcef-09b9-44a9-857c-9c55f9aa2445)

Can anyone know if there are any problems with activating this feature in the Modern SharePoint Communication site?

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, there is no any side effect to activating the Video and Rich Media feature for a site collection.